# Find an upperbound for the rational function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^3 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2} = 0$$ so

$$\left\lvert \frac{x^3 + y^4}{x^2  + y^2} \right\rvert \le f(x, y)$$ for some simpler $f(x, y)$  whose limit is also $0$.

How do I find the function $f(x, y)$? In other words, how do I get the upper bound?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=r\cos{t}, y=r\sin{t}$, then $$\left\lvert \frac{x^3 + y^4}{x^2  + y^2} \right\rvert=|r(\cos^3{t}+r\sin^4{t})|\leq |r||1+r| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x^2+y^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the inequalities $x^2+y^2\ge x^2$ and $x^2+y^2\ge y^2$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\right|&\le \frac{|x|^3}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}\\\\
&\le |x|+y^2
\end{align}$$